# How can i auto deploy with gitlab-ci.yml on a remote server without GitLab Runner?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I want to auto deploy a simple docker-compose.yml file with database and api from gitlab-ci.yml. I have a ubuntu server running on a specific ip where i can pull the gitlab project and run it manualy with `docker-compose up -d`, but how can I achieve this automatically through gitlab-ci.yml, without using gitlab runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab CI ("Continuous Integration") inherently involves Gitlab Runners.

You can't use one without the other.

Whether you use a Gitlab Runner or not, you can achieve what you ask in a number of different ways, such as:

- Use `subprocess` to invoke system commands like `scp` to copy files over and `ssh <host> <command>` to run remote commands.
- Use [paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/) to do the same thing in a more Pythonic way.
- Use a provisioning tool such as [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/)

If you're not using a Gitlab Runner, your code would invoke these directly. For someone using a Gitlab Runner, their `.gitlab-ci.yml` would contain these scripts / script calls instead.